# How to change date from (YYYY-MM-DD) to (MM-DD-YYYY) in android?

Tags: android, date-format

I get a date value from webservice and set a value in Textview like ("yyyy-MM-dd"), then I tried to change ("MM-DD-YYYY") but I cannot fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change date format then use methods of  `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.